# Shopify: How to reuse components inside sections?

Tags: html, shopify, e-commerce, liquid

how are you?

I have a problem with a page I am trying to create for my store. It's a page with a headline plus 9 images, that could be easily achieved with a section (title + blocks) but this headline + photos (lets call it gallery) appears **three times on my page.**

How to repeat the same section, different data on the same page? So far I have the template layout for my page, I know how to add sections and snippets, the issue is how to reuse that gallery section containing title + photos.

For example, I could do this on my page layout:

```
{% section 'page-street-template' %}
{% section 'page-street-template2' %}
{% section 'page-street-template3' %}
```

But that's quite ugly and I will need to repeat everything three times.

Thanks

[image: ![The page]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxBfI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Sections are not repeatable outside the index page.

You can call the same section multiply times, but the data will be the same. Once you change a section data this will be applied for each page you use this section for.

If you like to use repeatable data and you don't rely on the blocks for the section at the moment, you can use blocks, since they are repeatable and you can have different data.

If you are using blocks you can create a more complex logic where you will have a different type of block for your heading and a separate one for your image, then you will need to split your content in order to achieve the above layout you provided.

That said if you use the section on a different page the blocks data will be applied to it as well.

---

So you can't use sections on multiply pages with different content. The content shared between all pages (except the homepage if the section is designated to be used there as well).

If you like to have a different dynamic content for different pages the best approach will be to use an Metafields APP.

Other than that you can use other approaches that will require more coding like:

- prefixed page, where you prefix pages and called using `pages[handle]` to get their content
- navigations, where you can create a navigation with the same name as the page and based on the links call each page `link in linklists[page.handle].links => link.object.content`

---

TLDR; no you can't reuse the same section on the page with different data, but you can go around this limitation.